# Create a form that uses attributes from 2 different models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form that blends elements from a couple different places. I think the best way to do this may be 2 different forms and showing them on the same page, unless someone else can help me pop it all into one form?

I see no problem using 2 forms but I'm kind of unsure how to proceed (and maybe I don't need to!).

I have 2 classes that are somewhat related: Person(User) and Friend and they share PersonBenefits.

models would look like this:

```
class PersonBenefit(models.Model):
     benefit = models.ForeignKey(Benefit, null=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Friend(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     has_benefit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     ben_id_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
     person = models.ForeignKey(User)

 #good, better, best
class BenefitType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Benefit(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(BenefitType)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

The forms.py looks something like this:

```
class GoodBenefitForm(forms.Form):
    benefit = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Benefit.objects.filter(type__name='Good'),
        widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class':'g-1-3'})
    )
 # THIS SHOWS A LIST OF ALL THE FRIENDS FOR THIS USER - DISPLAYS THEIR NAMES NICELY WITH CHECKBOXES
    friend = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Friend.objects.none(),
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    )
 # I WANT THIS TO BE A BUNCH OF TEXTBOXES INSTEAD OF CHECKBOXES - ONE FOR EACH FRIEND FOR THE USER
    friend_group_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Friend.objects.none(),
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        queryset = Friend.objects.filter(person=self.user)
        super(FriendBenefitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['friend'].queryset = queryset
        self.fields['friend_group_id'].queryset = queryset
```

Essentially I'm trying to get the form to display a list of 'friends' with checkboxes, then next to their name, display a text field that the user can enter a `ben_id_num`

Again, after reading, I'm thinking that having 2 separate forms may be the best way to go, but I'm not sure if maybe I'm just doing something stupid in my forms.py as is and it can work with just 1 form.

This would essentially be:

For each 'Friend', display a little form that has a checkbox with the friends name and a text field immediately following it (which corresponds to their `ben_id_num`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a [Django Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/), which lets you edit a model with one or more related models in the same form.

I've had some success using the `CreateWithInlinesView` and `UpdateWithInlinesView` provided by [django-extra-views](http://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#createwithinlinesview-and-updatewithinlinesview) to make formsets a little easier to manage.

If the form does require a lot of custom logic, there's nothing stopping you from adding all of those fields to a custom form, then writing custom logic in a `FormView`'s `form_valid(self, form)` method.

The nice thing about Django is that you can use its helper classes when you can, but you can always handle things manually if you need a more custom solution.

Comment: I'm reading the docs on formset now - and I think that may be just what the doctor ordered. Trying it out now to see what I can come up with! If it works, this will be a treat!

Comment: @Hanny Formsets take a little bit of practice, but they're really handy once you get used to them. Good luck!

Comment: This worked well. I actually found the modelformset_factory to be just what I was looking for!